# Django "Method \"POST\" not allowed."

Tags: django

When I test my endpoints using Postman I get the message `Method \"POST\" not allowed` when I try to create a new truck using my createTruck function. I am able to delete, update, and get trucks from my database. Also I am able to create a new truck in Django Admin.

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createTruck(request):
    data = request.data
    user = request.user

    truck = Truck.objects.create(
        user=user,
        image=data['image'],
        make=data['make'],
        prototype=data['prototyp'],
        year=data['year'],
        serviceInterval=data['serviceInterval'],
        nextService=data['nextService'],
        seats=data['seats'],
        bedLength=data['bedLength'],
        color=data['color'],
        vin=data['vin'],
        currentMileage=data['currentMileage']
    )
    print("request", request)

    serializer = TruckSerializer(truck, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['DELETE'])
def deleteTruck(request, pk):
    truck = Truck.objects.get(id=pk)
    truck.delete()
    return Response('Truck Deleted!')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('trucks/', views.getTrucks, name="trucks"),
    path('trucks/<str:pk>/', views.getTruck, name="truck"),
    path('trucks/create/', views.createTruck, name="create-truck"),
    path('trucks/delete/<str:pk>/', views.deleteTruck, name="delete-truck"),
    path('trucks/update/<str:pk>/', views.updateTruck, name="update-truck"),
]
```

I might be passing in user wrong, but I'm not sure.

The Postman URL is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/trucks/create/
```

The body is

```
{
        "user": 1,
        "image": "/images/2016-tundra-600x400.jpeg",
        "make": "Toyota",
        "prototype": "Tundra",
        "year": 2016,
        "serviceInterval": 720,
        "nextService": 600,
        "seats": 2,
        "bedLength": "5.50",
        "color": "blak",
        "vin": "0989098ad2321",
        "currentMileage": 20000
    }
```

Comment: What url did you use to create the truck?

Comment: Using `trucks/create` is being caught by `trucks/<str:pk>/`, (meaning it goes through `views.getTruck`) since `create` can match `<str:pk>`. Is your pk actually a string?

Comment: no its a number. should i try int?

Comment: Yes better to use `<int:pk>`

Comment: Thank you Brian, you were right it was going through getTruck. I am no longer getting the POST not allowed message.

Comment: That's great to hear!

Comment: you're gona want to look into how to do proper methods and url structure in django. you should have a GET to `/trucks` to get a list of trucks, a POST to `/trucks` to create a truck, and a GET to `/trucks/:id` to get a specific truck, a PUT/PATCH to `/trucks/:id` to update a truck and a DELETE to `/trucks/:id` to delete a truck, rather than have 5 different URLs for these operations.  Django makes this pretty easy to implement if you follow their tutorial.

Comment: Thank you @bryan60 I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your URL pattern. It is a URL pattern conflict, that create-truck-pattern tries to get the truck with `pk:create`. The standard solution is to change the type of pk from str to int. But the other solution is to change URL priority in your patterns and move create-truck on step upper.

Recommended solution:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('trucks/', views.getTrucks, name="trucks"),
    path('trucks/<int:pk>/', views.getTruck, name="truck"),
    path('trucks/create/', views.createTruck, name="create-truck"),
    path('trucks/delete/<str:pk>/', views.deleteTruck, name="delete-truck"),
    path('trucks/update/<str:pk>/', views.updateTruck, name="update-truck"),
]
```

other solution:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('trucks/', views.getTrucks, name="trucks"),
    path('trucks/create/', views.createTruck, name="create-truck"),
    path('trucks/<str:pk>/', views.getTruck, name="truck"),
    path('trucks/delete/<str:pk>/', views.deleteTruck, name="delete-truck"),
    path('trucks/update/<str:pk>/', views.updateTruck, name="update-truck"),
]
```